# Disable Wallpaper Autoresize and Scroll

Tags: updates, 8.1-oreo, default-applications, wallpaper

My RCA Voyager Pro (Android 8.1.0) recently got a firmware update. Since the update, I have not been able to set a wallpaper without it "zooming in."

Take these screenshots for example. When I select the image I want to use as my wallpaper, it allows me to choose the orientation and zoom before clicking "✓ Set Wallpaper."

[image]

Before the update, the wallpaper would be set exactly as it looks in the preview. However, after the update, the wallpaper will become enlarged and will scroll as I swipe from right to left:

[image]

Here is a side-by-side comparison of how the wallpaper is the in preview (before the wallpaper is set), and how it is on home screen (after the wallpaper is set):

[image]

Is there a way I can disable this "auto-zooming?" I miss the way it used to be, where my wallpaper was the same on the home screen as it was in the preview, and did not "scroll" as I browsed my apps.